# Creating Seaborn Barplots with Hues

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, seaborn

I have a dataset which contains the pageviews to all the pages (URLs) for a website for every single day for a few years.

For example, there might be 25 entries with the same date, each corresponding to a different URL and the associated pageviews to that URL.

I have added new columns in the pandas dataframe to include "Year" and "Month".

Now I would like to create a barplot to show the top 10 pages visited for each year using Seaborn.

I am able to make the plot for the entire dataset (i.e. every single page), but I can't figure out how to do so for just the top 10 most visited pages.

This is what I currently have, where `'Page path level 1'` is the URL and `content` is the dataframe.

```
sns.countplot(x = 'Page path level 1', data = content, hue = 'Year')
```

Here's a snippet of the dataframe:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Considering `Pageviews` is the feature that you want to consider for defining top 10, you may use the below code.

```
sns.countplot(x = 'Page path level 1', data = content.groupby(by=['Page path level 1','year'])['Pageviews'].sum().reset_index().sort_values(by=['Pageviews'], ascending=False).head(10), hue = 'Year')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nlargest` to subset the values you plot.

```
import pandas as pd

# Instead of data = content use 
data = content[content.Pageviews.isin(content.Pageviews.nlargest(10))]
```